# HTTP 500 when sending SMS using SMPP

Tags: php, smpp

I am using [SMPP](https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp) library to send and receive SMS.

When i go to start the connection `$transport->open();` my browser gives HTTP 500 server error.

Appreciate if you can help me on this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: 500 server error is an error on the server side. We'd need to see the server code to comment.

Answer (score 0):

See PHP's log. 
If you are using apache, open your error_log, it may contains useful information.